Kafka partially connecting to cassandra to write streams of data
I am trying to write streams of data from kafka to cassandra on docker container automated with Airflow DAG. Here are the things that are working as expected.

DAG sending data and I can see the output on control center.
spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 spark_stream.py working as expected

INFO:root:Spark connection created successfully!
INFO:root:kafka dataframe created successfully

INFO:root:Cassandra connection created successfully!
INFO:root:Keyspace created successfully!
INFO:root:Table created successfully!
INFO:root:Streaming is being started..


I can see the Keyspace and the table created on cqlsh

Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9042
[cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh> describe spark_streams;

CREATE KEYSPACE spark_streams WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE spark_streams.created_users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    address text,
    email text,
    first_name text,
    gender text,
    last_name text,
    phone text,
    picture text,
    post_code text,
    registered_date text,
    username text
) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = false
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND memtable = 'default'
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';

cassandra@cqlsh> select * from spark_streams.created_users ;

 id | cleaned_tweet | date | lat | lng | original_tweet | place | sentiment | tweet
----+---------------+------+-----+-----+----------------+-------+-----------+-------

The error:
For some reason spark fails to write the data to cassandra and throws this error:
24/08/06 18:21:40 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support MicroBatchWrite[epoch: 0, writer: CassandraBulkWrite(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@75f79aff,com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector@3698a9ca,TableDef(spark_streams,created_users,ArrayBuffer(ColumnDef(id,PartitionKeyColumn,UUIDType)),ArrayBuffer(),Stream(ColumnDef(cleaned_tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(date,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(lat,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(lng,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(original_tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(place,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(sentiment,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType)),Stream(),false,false,Map()),WriteConf(BytesInBatch(1024),1000,Partition,LOCAL_QUORUM,false,false,5,None,TTLOption(DefaultValue),TimestampOption(DefaultValue),true,None),StructType(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(original_tweet,StringType,true),StructField(tweet,StringType,true),StructField(lat,StringType,true),StructField(lng,StringType,true),StructField(place,StringType,true),StructField(date,StringType,true),StructField(sentiment,StringType,true),StructField(cleaned_tweet,StringType,true)),org.apache.spark.SparkConf@618b8d53)] is aborting.
24/08/06 18:21:40 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support MicroBatchWrite[epoch: 0, writer: CassandraBulkWrite(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@75f79aff,com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector@3698a9ca,TableDef(spark_streams,created_users,ArrayBuffer(ColumnDef(id,PartitionKeyColumn,UUIDType)),ArrayBuffer(),Stream(ColumnDef(cleaned_tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(date,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(lat,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(lng,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(original_tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(place,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(sentiment,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(tweet,RegularColumn,VarCharType)),Stream(),false,false,Map()),WriteConf(BytesInBatch(1024),1000,Partition,LOCAL_QUORUM,false,false,5,None,TTLOption(DefaultValue),TimestampOption(DefaultValue),true,None),StructType(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(original_tweet,StringType,true),StructField(tweet,StringType,true),StructField(lat,StringType,true),StructField(lng,StringType,true),StructField(place,StringType,true),StructField(date,StringType,true),StructField(sentiment,StringType,true),StructField(cleaned_tweet,StringType,true)),org.apache.spark.SparkConf@618b8d53)] aborted.

This is how I create the table:
def create_table(session):
   
    session.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams.created_users (
                    
                    original_tweet TEXT,
                    tweet TEXT,
                    lat TEXT,
                    lng TEXT,
                    place TEXT,
                    date TEXT,
                    sentiment TEXT,
                    cleaned_tweet TEXT,
                    id UUID PRIMARY KEY
                    );
                    """)
    logging.info("Table created successfully!")

This is the schema:
def create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("original_tweet", StringType(), False),
        StructField("tweet", StringType(), False),
        StructField("lat", StringType(), False),
        StructField("lng", StringType(), False),
        StructField("place", StringType(), False),
        StructField("date", StringType(), False),
        StructField("sentiment", StringType(), False),
        StructField("cleaned_tweet", StringType(), False),
    ])

    sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)
    return sel

And this is my Kafka_stream.py:
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import uuid

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airscholar',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 8, 1, 10, 00)

}

def get_data():
    import pandas as pd
    from json import loads, dumps
    import os, logging

    df = pd.read_csv('./dataframe.csv')
    
    logging.info(f"DataFrame shape: {df.shape}")
    df.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'id', 'mentions'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    return df
    

def format_data(data):  
    import os, logging  
    result = data.to_json(orient='records')
    logging.info(f"Formatted data to JSON: {result[:100]}...")
    return result
    

def stream_data():
    import json
    from json import loads, dumps
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
    import time
    import logging
    import traceback

    
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'], max_block_ms=5000)
    curr_time = time.time()

    while True:
        if time.time() > curr_time + 60: #1minute
            break
        try:
            
            df = get_data()
            data_json = format_data(df)
            data_list = json.loads(data_json)
            
            for record in data_list[0:2]:
                
                record['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
                
                logging.info(f"Sending record: {record}")
                producer.send('users_created', json.dumps(record).encode('utf-8'))
            logging.info(f"Sent {len(data_list)} records")
            producer.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'An error occured: {e}')
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            continue
   
# stream_data()
with DAG('user_automation', default_args=default_args, schedule='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:
    streaming_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'stream_twitter_data_from_api',
        python_callable=stream_data
    )

I tried writing the dataframe to a csv file and to the console before streaming and that throws the exact same error.
